# How to apply the inclusion exclusion principle

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

How can I apply the inclusion exclusion principle when I have
$$|Q|+|P|+|R|-|Q\cup P| -|Q\cup R|-|P\cup R|+|Q\cap P\cap R|$$

I'm not sure how to convert the unions into intersections here $$"|Q\cup P| -|Q\cup R|-|P\cup R|"$$ so that I can apply the inclusion exclusion principle.

Comment: Well... With the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Though looking at this thing I'm not exactly sure what the goal is.

Comment: I believe all those unions are actually supposed to be intersections.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that all the unions are supposed to be intersections. However, all the unions are currently right now unions and I'm not sure how to convert them into intersections.

Comment: "*how to convert them into intersections*" Using the inclusion exclusion principle, of course. But you forgot to state what the actual goal of the exercise is.

Comment: Please provide an actual problem statement. It is unclear what the problem or goal is here.

Comment: This looks like an expansion of $n(P \cup Q \cup R) $. Drawing a Venn Diagram should help, as well as using the formula for the (number of elements in) union of two sets, $\ n(A\cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A \cap B)$.